# Plotting in horizontal with percentage on the bar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data frame say df =

```
FunderCode                  
HCPL1   1%  18% 50% 30% 1%
HCPL2   1%  16% 44% 37% 3%
HCPL3   1%  17% 40% 39% 3%
HCPL4   1%  20% 40% 34% 5%
```

I wanted to plot it like the following

[image]

I could get the following using

```
Piv_age_per.plot( kind = 'bar', stacked = True , legend = True)
```

I wanted a diagram with percentage on the bars, if there is inbuilt command to achieve that?
[image]g plot
I could use the following code to generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd #1.4.4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # 3.5.2
# Python 3.10.6

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(5))
data.loc['HCPL1'] = [1,  18, 50, 30, 1]
data.loc['HCPL2'] = [1,  16, 44, 37, 3]
data.loc['HCPL3'] = [1,  17, 40, 39, 3]
data.loc['HCPL4'] = [1,  20, 40, 34, 5]
cumulative = data.cumsum(axis=1)

n_rows, n_cols = data.shape
y_pos = range(n_rows)
height = 0.35
colors = ['blue', 'darkorange', 'gray', 'yellow', 'darkblue']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

for i in range(n_cols):
    left = cumulative[i]-data[i]
    labels = [f'{value:.1f}%' for value in data[i]]
    ploted = ax.barh(y_pos, data[i], height, 
                     align='center', 
                     left=left, 
                     zorder=2, 
                     color=colors[i])
    ax.bar_label(ploted, label_type='center', fontsize=12, labels=labels)

ax.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=data.index)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=20)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 101, 10))
ax.grid(axis='x', zorder=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the following error "AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'
"

Comment: The `bar_label` is available since Matplotlib 3.4.3. Maybe you need to update. Tip: Use virtual environments.

Comment: Can I use virtual environment in google colab?

Comment: I don't really know about Google Colab. You can search for virtual environments on YouTube. I used Matplotlib 3.5.2, Pandas 1.4.4 and Python 3.10.6. Figure added above...

Comment: Thanks it work now, I can update in Colab